# PHP foreach loop performance

Tags: php, performance, for-loop

I have an application that makes a request to `Amazon Elastic Search` which in some cases returns as many as 1000 records. Once I retrieve the records, I iterate through them and shape the data with very simple code which populates a new array.

Here's an example where $recipes is an array from ES and `$recipe` is and individual record and `$filter_options` is a new array I'm building:

```
$filter_options['materials']['classes'][] = [
   'id' => $recipe['material']['class']['tid'],
   'name' => $recipe['material']['class']['name'],
];
```

There are about ten other similar methods that are performed on each record. It takes a considerable amount of time to iterate through all of the records and I'm wondering if upgrading my server may help speed up the process. A faster machine. More ram, etc. Are there any other ideas of ways to shape larges amounts of data?

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't look like `$recipe` is an array of records, this looks like just one record.

Comment: Did you mean something like `foreach ($recipes as $recipe)`?

Comment: It's really hard to talk about performance in the abstract like this. We need to see more code to tell if you're using an inefficient algorithm. And you need to use performance monitoring tools to figure out what the bottleneck is on your machine.